# SGD optimizer, lr value with loop over batch and epoch, in pytorch

Tags: python, pytorch, scheduler

I am puzzling on how to optimize `lr` value, when I loop over the batch and epoch. I want to iterate for all epochs and keep the best. The same time, i iterate for batch size, and the `lr` value is getting updated (it should stay fixed in the batch loop), thus in the next epoch is already small.

In the code, we have `X_train,X_test,y_train,y_test` already.

```
# Define the model
model = nn.Sequential(
nn.Linear(X_train.shape[1], 24),
nn.ReLU(),
nn.Linear(24, 12),
nn.ReLU(),
nn.Linear(12, 6),
nn.ReLU(),
nn.Linear(6, 1)
)

# loss function and optimizer
loss_fn = nn.MSELoss()  # mean square error

optimizer = optim.SGD(model.parameters(), lr=0.01)

scheduler = lr_scheduler.LinearLR(optimizer, start_factor=1, end_factor=0.01, 
total_iters=100)


n_epochs = 10000   # number of epochs to run
batch_size = 64  # size of each batch
batch_start = torch.arange(0, len(X_train), batch_size)

# Hold the best model
best_mse = np.inf   # init to infinity
best_weights = None
history = []

for epoch in range(n_epochs):
    model.train()
    for start in batch_start:
        # take a batch
        X_batch = X_train[start:start+batch_size]
        y_batch = y_train[start:start+batch_size]
        # forward pass
        y_pred = model(X_batch)
        loss = loss_fn(y_pred, y_batch)
        # backward pass
        # set optimizer to zero grad
        # to remove previous epoch gradients
        optimizer.zero_grad()
        # backward propagation
        loss.backward()
        # update weights
        optimizer.step()
        # print progress
    # evaluate accuracy at end of each epoch
    model.eval()
    y_pred = model(X_test)
    mse = loss_fn(y_pred, y_test)
    mse = float(mse)
    history.append(mse)
    scheduler.step()
    # print("Epoch %d: LIN lr %.5f" % (epoch,optimizer.param_groups[0]["lr"] ))
    if mse < best_mse:
        best_mse = mse
        best_weights = copy.deepcopy(model.state_dict())
```

AFAIK, the `lr` value is updated in BOTH the `optimizer.step()`
and `scheduler.step()`.

How can I fix the `lr` value, within the batch loop (i.e. don't update the `lr` when the `opitmizer.step()` is called.

Comment: Do you want to find the learning rate that gives the best MSE after a complete training? Please note that when you tune the learning rate as a hyperparameter you usually want to tune the initial learning rate (and optionally the learning rate schedule). It doesn't make sense to change the learning rate manually at every epoch, it would require the tuning of each learning rate of each training iteration (so in total n_epochs * n_batches).

Comment: Hmm, two approaches. 1) Is any automatic way to let the algorithm optimize multiple hypermarameters? Similar to the gridsearchcv? 2) what I want is the lr to decrease only with epoches. When it's on the internal loop (batches) it should have a constant value from whatever the current epoch has.

Comment: 1) "Let the algorithm optimize multiple hyperparams", which algorithm? SGD? Or are you asking about other hyperparameter optimization algorithms besides grid search?
2) Since you are using SGD and not Adam or other optimizers with adaptive learning rate, your current code should do exactly what you are describing, i.e. lr decreasing only once per epoch, as your scheduler.step() is called once per epoch. Please provide more details or the output that shows the learning rate decreasing multiple times per epoch.